# How to register every day local notification at certain time?

Tags: notifications, coronasdk

How can I realize everyday local notifications in my app? So at first run I need to register first local notification at 14:00 and then everyday at 14:00 notification should appear.

User can change this time in app's settings.

How to do this mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the notifcations on your end, but to make a timer that countsdown to a certain time every day, you would need to do something like this:

```
local targetDate = os.time{ year=2014, month=11, day=8, hour=0, sec=0 } -- Get the date that you want to count down to, in seconds 
local text = false

local function enterFrame(event)
    if text then text:removeSelf() end -- Everyframe, remove the old text object
    local timeRemaining = (targetDate-os.time())    -- Take the difference between the target time and the current time
    local days = timeRemaining / 86400      -- get the number of days left by dividing the remaining seconds by the number of seconds in a day
    local hours = days%1 * 24           -- get the number of hours left by multiplying the remainder by the number hours in a day
    local minutes = hours%1 * 60            -- get the number of minutes by multiplying the remainder by the number of minutes in an hour
    local seconds = math.floor( minutes%1 * 60 + 0.5)  -- multiply the remainder one more time by the number of seconds in a minute, and round to the nearest second. 
     -- make a new text object to display all the info
    text = display.newText( "Will be available in "..math.floor(days).." days "..math.floor(hours).." hrs "..math.floor(minutes).." mins "..seconds.." secs ", 25, 140)
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", enterFrame )
```

You can repurpose your code to work with your project, but you need to use OS time and do certain calculations to each variable in order to get the time.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! And in **notificationListener** I should call this: `localNotif = system.scheduleNotification( 86400, reminderOptions )`